# Why does my filter stream return all objects with the "same" element name?

Tags: java

I have my objects in the a list and my goal is to modify the elements within the object. To first do this, I'm  searching for name element within the object so I can identify which object I'd like to modify and then go ahead and modify it.
The problem is, I have 3 objects with the name "Harry Potter" in it. It goes like:

1. Harry Potter
2. Harry Potter 1 (*Renamed to -  Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*)
3. Harry Potter 2 (*Renamed to - Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*)

After I search for the object with an element name of "Harry Potter" it returns all 3 objects, but I'm confused since I thought it would specifically return the object with the element name "Harry Potter" not the rest. It works if I enter the name where there's only one existing object with that element name, but it seems if there's multiple objects with at least a mention of the same name, it'll return those objects too, since like you saw I renamed those two other movies with a more specific name and it still returned all

1. Why is this happening?
2. After the first issue is solved, how can I then go ahead and let the user enter values for all the elements within the object to modify the existing values of those elements

Main Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {

        File file = new File("items.xml");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Items itemData = (Items) un.unmarshal(file);

        List<Item> items = itemData.getItem();

        for(Item e: items){
            System.out.println("\nDataType : "+e.getDataType());
            System.out.println("Name : "+e.getName());
            System.out.println("Data : "+e.getData());
            System.out.println("Group : "+e.getGroup());
            System.out.println("Sub Categories : " + e.getItems());
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }

        System.out.println("'\n\n------------- Options ---------------");
        System.out.println("\n1. Search Items by Group");
        System.out.println("\n2. Modify Movie");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if(choice == 1){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the group name you're searching for: ");
            String search = scan.nextLine();

            List<Item> filteredByGroup = items.stream()
                    .filter(i ->i.getGroup().equals(search))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            filteredByGroup.forEach(System.out::println);

        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the movie you would like to modify: ");
            String search = scan.nextLine();

            Optional<Item> item = items.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(search))
                    .findFirst();

            System.out.println(item.toString());

        }

        else{
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid option!");
        }
    }
}
```

Item class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;
    private Items items;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDataType(){
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType){
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getGroup(){
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                "\n\tName: " + name +
                "\n\tData: " + data +
                "\n\tGroup: " + group +
                "\n\tItems: " + items + "\n";
    }
}
```

Items class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items {
    private List<Item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + item ;
    }
}
```

XML File

```
<items> 
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Rush Hour</name>
            <data>1</data>
            <group>Comedy</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter</name>
            <data>2</data>
            <group>Fiction</group>
            <items>
                  <item>
                        <dataType>Number</dataType>
                        <name>Harry Potter and the Goblet Of Fire</name>
                        <data>3</data>
                        <group>Fiction</group>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                        <dataType>Number</dataType>
                        <name>Harry Potter and the Chamber of secrets</name>
                        <data>4</data>
                        <group>Fiction</group>
                  </item>
            </items>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Men In Black</name>
            <data>5</data>
            <group>Action</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Coming to America</name>
            <data>6</data>
            <group>Comedy</group>
      </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Where is the code for `Item`?

Comment: @JimGarrison code was updated with the classes

Comment: @user another option I have is to search all objects by group name, the getGroup just filters all the objects that are in the same group and return the values

Comment: Can we see the xml file? Is "Harry Potter" a group name?

Comment: No, harry potter is the name of the movie, and it's within the group called "fiction". I'll update the post to show the xml file also

Comment: Why does _Harry Potter 2_ ***contain*** _Harry Potter 3_ and _4_?

Comment: @JimGarrison that was the structure I was given to work with

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is working correctly. There is only one object with name "Harry Potter" returned with all it's sub-items "Harry Potter 1" and "Harry Potter 2". You probably didn't notice that "Harry Potter 1" and "Harry Potter 2" items are child elements to "Harry Potter" item. Consider to change your XML to following and you should get expected behavior:

```
<items> 
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Rush Hour</name>
            <data>1</data>
            <group>Comedy</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter</name>
            <data>2</data>
            <group>Fiction</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter and the Goblet Of Fire</name>
            <data>3</data>
            <group>Fiction</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter and the Chamber of secrets</name>
            <data>4</data>
            <group>Fiction</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Men In Black</name>
            <data>5</data>
            <group>Action</group>
      </item>
</items>
```

To answer second question, after you filter items which will be modified u should use `map()` function which allows you to modify all contents of stored objects inside the stream and then collect them as you did in the first case.

Comment: I do understand that harry potter 2 and 3 were children of harry potter 1, but in this instance, that was the structure I was given to work with, so changing the xml file to your structure won't suffice since I thought about that already. In any case, won't I be able to just return them individually instead of parent and child?

Comment: If you cant change the structure of XML data then you can use flatMap() function over the stream before filtering to virtually flatten data so items inside stream will be same as you would get when streaming over XML i have provided. I suggest you to read documentation or do some tutorial's with stream's flatMap() function as it might be hard for some people to understand. Data you have been provided should really follow XML structure i have specified since child item's of "Harry Potter" do not benefit from it's parent data at all and there is no reason to use such structure.